# Android N Developer Preview: Camera support takes a third value

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have a Nexus 6P. I'm investigating why [OpenCamera](http://opencamera.sourceforge.net) has stopped working on Android N Developer Preview (I'm not a developer, just a user). I have found the following piece of code that might be causing the problem: [CameraControllerManager2.java:62](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencamera/code/ci/master/tree/src/net/sourceforge/opencamera/CameraController/CameraControllerManager2.java#l62)

I created a new Android project, and added the following function:

```
...
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = "MainActivity";
    ...
    public void test(int cameraId) {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            String cameraIdS = manager.getCameraIdList()[cameraId];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraIdS);
            int support = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL);
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera support: " + support);
        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Calling `test(0)`, the console output on my device is:

```
04-22 15:16:54.263 11578-11578/test.myapplication D/MainActivity: Camera support: 3
```

When I look up the possible values of `support` ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL)), they must be [0, 1 or 2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED), but how is `support` taking the value of 3? Is it supposed to be a bitmask or something worse is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the docs for the shipping version of Android. At the present time, Android N is in a developer preview, and the docs are [elsewhere](http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html#docs-dl).

There is a new `INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_3` value for that characteristic, described as:

> ...devices additionally support YUV reprocessing and RAW image capture, along with additional output stream configurations.